# php changing variable on database output

Tags: php, database

Hey i was looking here on other posts on stackoverflow and did't find an answer

i have a problem with changing variable on row output

i am inserting url to database with a var. for example

```
http://www.sitename.com?id=$site_id
```

on my php file i have a variable called $site_id

```
$site_id = 5;
```

in the end i am using the url and the $site_id for using header but with a $site_id

```
$url = $row['url'];
header("Location: ".$url);
```

how can i change the variable?

Comment: What variable you want to change ?

Comment: so the text in your db record literally contains the characters `=`, `$`, `s`, `i`, etc...?

Comment: If you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how the site works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a simple string replace like this:

(Also i hope you made sure that you are save against SQL Injection for your DB)

```
$site_id = 5;
$url = 'http://www.sitename.com?id=$site_id';  //As an example from DB
$url = str_replace('$site_id', $site_id, $url);
header("Location: $url");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `$url` to store `$row['url']`.. You can use any variable of your choice..

Comment: Wrong, the variable in single quotes don't get evaluated! Also if you would use `$row['url']` in quotes it also is not going to work

Comment: I agree I got the `header` one wrong, but `$row['url']` is being fetched from database..So it right to use it this way.